# Problems displaying tkinter dialog updates in Windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a larger application that calls a number of processes that can take a long time. So I thought I would post a sub-dialog that indicated how many steps had been completed. In the main module, I have:

```
  sdroot  = Toplevel()
  sdroot.geometry('+240+200')
  self.sd = StatusDialog( sdroot, "Completed %d Mutation(s)" )
  sdroot.focus_set()
  sdroot.lift()
  sdroot.wait_visibility()
  sdroot.grab_set()
  self.matrix.mutate( self.myzmm, self.mycomplex.pdb, self.sd  )
  sdroot.destroy()
```

which is supposed to display my status dialog. The mutate function then updates that dialog with the code-

```
def mutate( self, z, pdbfile, sd = '' ):
     ...
     cnt += 1
     if sd:
        sd.update( cnt  )
```

The code for the status dialog is:

```
class StatusDialog:
      def __init__( self, master, fmtstr ):
         self.parent = master
         self.parent.title( "Calculation Status" )
         self.state  = StringVar()
         self.fmtstr = fmtstr
         self.sstr   = self.fmtstr % 0
         self.state.set( self.sstr )

         self.frame = Frame(self.parent, relief=RIDGE, borderwidth=2 )
         self.frame.pack()

         self.label=Label(  self.frame,  textvariable = self.state )
         self.label.pack( padx = 20, pady = 25 )

      def update( self, cnt  ):
         self.sstr  = self.fmtstr % cnt
         self.state.set( self.sstr )
         self.parent.update_idletasks()
```

It works perfectly with python 2.4 and RHEL 5. However, on Windows XP (python 2.6), the dialog posts, but I see nothing but an empty white box. No status message.

Could someone help me out? I am not sure whether I am doing something fundamentally wrong and Linux is letting me get away with it or there is something special I need to do to get the dialog to display in Windows XP.

Comment: update_idletasks() might be not good enough. In general it is best to have the event loop running and let it handle updating, but if you have a cpu bound task running and are using Python with its GIL you cannot simply place the calculation in a thread like you would in Tcl. So maybe try replacing update_idletasks() with a full update() instead.